# Push SurveyJS data to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to push a form data to MongoDB. I'm using NodeJS as a web server. I'm running both of these on my laptop.

Below is the code and note sure which part needs to be changed. The database name is 'research', collection name is 'biomaker'.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://surveyjs.azureedge.net/1.0.48/survey.jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="padding:50px">
  <div id="app">
    <h2>{{ message }}</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="surveyContainer"></div>
</div>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Online Questionnaire'
  }
})

Survey.Survey.cssType = "bootstrap";
var surveyJSON = {
  pages: [{
    name: "save_data_1",
    elements: [{
        type: "text",
        name: "question3",
        title: "First Name"
      },
      {
        type: "text",
        name: "question4",
        title: "Last Name"
      },
      {
        type: "text",
        name: "question5",
        title: "Date Of Birth"
      },
      {
        type: "text",
        name: "question6",
        title: "Country"
      }
    ]
  }]
}

function sendDataToServer(survey) {
  alert("The results are:" + JSON.stringify(survey.data) + ". The results can be sent to a API server and save to a database.");

  var data = {
    "request": "save_data_1",
    sdata: survey.data
  };

  $.ajax({
    headers: {},
    type: "POST",
    url: "127.0.0.1:27017/research.biomarker",
    contentType: "application/json",
    charset: "utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    error: function(jqXHR, error, errorThrown) {
      if (jqXHR.status) {
        alert(jqXHR.responseText);
      } else {
        alert("Something went wrong");
      }
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function(c, textStatus, request) {
    },
  })
}

var survey = new Survey.Model(surveyJSON);
$("#surveyContainer").Survey({
  model: survey,
  onComplete: sendDataToServer
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #dbecec;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? You haven't described anything about the issues you're having, nor have you even asked a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out that needed to build a form in html and then push using get to a database like firebase or mongodb